# Can the multiclass classification be modified to binary classification for better accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I've achieved good accuracy in binary classification problems, but I'm facing challenges when it comes to multi-class classification tasks.

While tackling a natural language processing challenge involving the classification of reviews into ratings on a scale of 1 to 5, I enhanced the performance by redefining the ratings. I assigned a value of 1 for ratings greater than 3 and 0 for ratings less than or equal to 3, resulting in a substantial improvement in accuracy.

My question is, Is a model considered good when it classifies data into just two distinct categories, as compared to a multi-class classification model that exhibits lower accuracy.

Comment: I will not comment on your main question about multiclass vs binary, however you could consider continuing down the path you are on now; i.e., further refine the classification by now distinguishing between 4 and 5 or 1 and 2.  In essence, you are building a sort of decision tree of neural networks.

Comment: Would you add the type of decision making models you tried for binary and multi classes dataset? It would help us understand your situation. I think the characteristic of your dataset also import factor.

Answer (score 1):

By making the problem binary, you are in all likelihood simplifying the decision boundary to be learned. You are not improving your 5-class classification accuracy as much as generating a good 2-class classification accuracy. You cannot really comment on if one accuracy is better than the other as they are not related.

If you used the 2-class predictions and broke them into further classes until you reached the original 5 classes, you might even end up at your original accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-class classifiers have a higher chance to misclassify a class for another that is proportional to the number of classes, say $k$. So, in general, when turning a binary classification problem into a multi-class one (for example by adding an extra class), you can expect lower accuracy just because correctly classifing $k$ classes is harder than $2$.

Don't mistake me, what I mean is that not necessary the multi-class model is worse than the binary one. There are problems in which some classes are similar to others, this may be your case too in which rating 2 and 3, or 4 and 5 can be considered quite similar. In your case, you want to also look at the *top-k accuracy* (top-3, for example) to see if the correct class is among the top-3 predicted classes.

You want also to consider that if you sum some of the predicted logits (or class probabilities) you can recover a binary classifier: in principle, you should expect this to be similar in performance than the binary one, although information about the $k$ classes introduces a different prior while learning - in your case, you should sum logits 0, 1, and 2 to obtain the negative class (rankings below or equal 3), and 3 and 4 for the positive class (or just do 1 - negative class prob.) Moreover, in case of *unbalanced classes*, fusing two classes or more in one may ease learning (because the imbalance would be mitigated), so increasing performance.

The last thing you want to consider is to have a binary classifier that performs a first "selection" of data samples. Say you're mostly interested in classifying worse reviews. If so, you can have a binary model that "filters out" the good reviews (also you want to tune the classification threshold in a way that is meaningful, i.e. trading the rate of type-1 and type-2 errors) leaving only the bad ones, which are further classified by a 3-class classifier. Such an approach is not said to be better than directly training a 5-class model, but can help at enhancing the accuracy on the negative reviews, as an example.

Regarding your question:

> Is a model considered good when it classifies data into just two distinct categories, as compared to a multi-class classification model that exhibits lower accuracy.

Again, comparing binary accuracy with the categorical one is not fair: top-k is a little better, but still not the same thing. A better  approach is to consider the rate of error (I mean whatever classification metric you like) obtained by summing over the relevant class probabilities (so that to recover a binary problem) and comparing that with what a binary classifier achieved. For example, you can compare precision/recall on class 0 (provided by a binary classifier) with the same metric but computed by summing over class 0, 1, 2, of the multi-class model.